# How can I get Gradle to use PMD 6.x categories?

Tags: gradle, pmd

I am using Gradle 4.5.1 and the standard Gradle plugin. I have specifically requested that my build use PMD 6.1.0, like so:

```
apply plugin: "pmd"

pmd {
    toolVersion = "6.1.0"
}

pmdMain {
    rulSets = ["java-basic"]
}
```

Everything passes, but I get a number of deprecation warnings in the console along the lines of this:

> Use Rule name `category/java/errorprone.xml/AvoidBranchingStatementAsLastInLoop` instead of the deprecated Rule name `rulesets/java/basic.xml/AvoidBranchingStatementAsLastInLoop`. PMD 7.0.0 will remove support for this deprecated Rule name usage.

My initial thought was to change the `pmdMain` block like so:

```
pmdMain {
    rulSets = ["java-errorprone"]
}
```

However, I get this error:

> Can't find resource 'null' for rule 'java-errorprone'.  Make sure the resource is a valid file or URL and is on the CLASSPATH. Here's the current classpath: `~\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.5.1-bin\a5vbgfvpwtoqz8v2cdivxz28k\gradle-4.5.1\lib\gradle-launcher-4.5.1.jar`

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Is Gradle's PMD plugin incompatible with PMD 6.x?

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party, but there's a typo in "rulSets". Mabye that's related to this issue.

Answer (score 6):

In PMD 6.0.0, the old rulesets were deprecated. The rules were reorganized into categories, and a greater push was made for people to create tailor made rulesets for their projects.

That is, the best practice would be for you to [write a custom ruleset](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.0.1/pmd_userdocs_understanding_rulesets.html) file selecting which rules to include from the [Java Rule Catalog](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.0.1/pmd_rules_java.html)

That being said, you can still include complete categories, even if not advisable. Under Gradle that would be done by:

```
pmdMain {
    rulSets = ["category/java/errorprone.xml"]
}
```

Notice the old rulesets, even if deprecated, will continue to work until PMD 7.0.0 is released. We plan to provide [migration tools for existing ruleset files](https://github.com/asarkar/pmd-migration-tool) along with easier ruleset generators to ease the transition.